# How to properly mask a numpy 2D array?

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, mask, masked-array

Say I have a two dimensional array of coordinates that looks something like

`x = array([[1,2],[2,3],[3,4]])`

Previously in my work so far, I generated a mask that ends up looking something like

`mask = [False,False,True]`

When I try to use this mask on the 2D coordinate vector, I get an error

```
newX = np.ma.compressed(np.ma.masked_array(x,mask))

>>>numpy.ma.core.MaskError: Mask and data not compatible: data size 
   is 6, mask size is 3.`
```

which makes sense, I suppose. So I tried to simply use the following mask instead:

```
mask2 = np.column_stack((mask,mask))
newX = np.ma.compressed(np.ma.masked_array(x,mask2))
```

And what I get is close:

`>>>array([1,2,2,3])`

to what  I would expect (and want):

`>>>array([[1,2],[2,3]])`

There must be an easier way to do this?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
import numpy as np
x[~np.array(mask)]
# array([[1, 2],
#        [2, 3]])
```

Or from [numpy masked array](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/maskedarray.baseclass.html#numpy.ma.MaskedArray.mask):

```
newX = np.ma.array(x, mask = np.column_stack((mask, mask)))
newX

# masked_array(data =
#  [[1 2]
#  [2 3]
#  [-- --]],
#              mask =
#  [[False False]
#  [False False]
#  [ True  True]],
#        fill_value = 999999)
```

Answer (score 15):

With `np.where` you can do all sorts of things:

```
x_maskd = np.where(mask, x, 0)
```

`np.where` takes three arguments, a `condition`, `x`, and `y`. All three arguments must be broadcast-able to the same shape. In locations where `mask` is  True, the `x` value is returned. Otherwise, the `y` value is returned.

Comment: Not many understand that `np.where` is a line-saver !

Answer (score 9):

Your `x` is 3x2:

```
In [379]: x
Out[379]: 
array([[1, 2],
       [2, 3],
       [3, 4]])
```

Make a 3 element boolean mask:

```
In [380]: rowmask=np.array([False,False,True])
```

That can be used to select the rows where it is True, or where it is False.  In both cases the result is 2d:

```
In [381]: x[rowmask,:]
Out[381]: array([[3, 4]])

In [382]: x[~rowmask,:]
Out[382]: 
array([[1, 2],
       [2, 3]])
```

This is without using the MaskedArray subclass.  To make such array, we need a mask that matches `x` in shape.  There isn't provision for masking just one dimension.

```
In [393]: xmask=np.stack((rowmask,rowmask),-1)  # column stack

In [394]: xmask
Out[394]: 
array([[False, False],
       [False, False],
       [ True,  True]], dtype=bool)

In [395]: np.ma.MaskedArray(x,xmask)
Out[395]: 
masked_array(data =
 [[1 2]
 [2 3]
 [-- --]],
             mask =
 [[False False]
 [False False]
 [ True  True]],
       fill_value = 999999)
```

Applying `compressed` to that produces a raveled array: `array([1, 2, 2, 3])`

Since masking is element by element, it could mask one element in row 1, 2 in row 2 etc.  So in general `compressing`, removing the masked elements, will not yield a 2d array.  The flattened form is the only general choice.

`np.ma` makes most sense when there's a scattering of masked values.  It isn't of much value if you want want to select, or deselect, whole rows or columns.

===============

Here are more typical masked arrays:

```
In [403]: np.ma.masked_inside(x,2,3)
Out[403]: 
masked_array(data =
 [[1 --]
 [-- --]
 [-- 4]],
             mask =
 [[False  True]
 [ True  True]
 [ True False]],
       fill_value = 999999)

In [404]: np.ma.masked_equal(x,2)
Out[404]: 
masked_array(data =
 [[1 --]
 [-- 3]
 [3 4]],
             mask =
 [[False  True]
 [ True False]
 [False False]],
       fill_value = 2)

In [406]: np.ma.masked_outside(x,2,3)
Out[406]: 
masked_array(data =
 [[-- 2]
 [2 3]
 [3 --]],
             mask =
 [[ True False]
 [False False]
 [False  True]],
       fill_value = 999999)
```

Answer (score 3):

If you have

```
A =  [[  8.   0. 165.  22. 164.  47. 184. 185.]
      [  0.   6. -74. -27.  63.  49. -46. -48.]
      [165. -74.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.]
      [ 22. -27.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.]
      [164.  63.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.]
      [ 47.  49.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.]
      [184. -46.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.]
      [185. -48.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.   0.]]
```

and your mask is

```
mask = np.array([True, True, True, False, True, False, True, False])
```

then your masked A becomes

```
A[mask, :][:, mask] = [[  8.   0. 165. 164. 184.]
                       [  0.   6. -74.  63. -46.]
                       [165. -74.   0.   0.   0.]
                       [164.  63.   0.   0.   0.]
                       [184. -46.   0.   0.   0.]]
```

Answer (score 2):

Since none of these solutions worked for me, I thought to write down what solution did, maybe it will useful for somebody else. I use python 3.x and I worked on two 3D arrays. One, which I call `data_3D` contains float values of recordings in a brain scan, and the other, `template_3D` contains integers which represent regions of the brain. I wanted to choose those values from `data_3D` corresponding to an integer `region_code` as per `template_3D`:

```
my_mask = np.in1d(template_3D, region_code).reshape(template_3D.shape)
data_3D_masked = data_3D[my_mask]
```

which gives me a 1D array of only relevant recordings.

Answer (score 1):

In your last example, the problem is not the mask.  It is your use of `compressed`.  From the docstring of `compressed`:

```
Return all the non-masked data as a 1-D array.
```

So `compressed` flattens the nonmasked values into a 1-d array.  (It has to, because there is no guarantee that the compressed data will have an n-dimensional structure.)

Take a look at the masked array before you compress it:

```
In [8]: np.ma.masked_array(x, mask2)

Out[8]: 
masked_array(data =
 [[1 2]
 [2 3]
 [-- --]],
             mask =
 [[False False]
 [False False]
 [ True  True]],
       fill_value = 999999)
```

Comment: You're right, its correct before I compress it. I will read the documentation for a way to remove masked elements while preserving array dimensionality. Thanks

Comment: If I understand what you are trying to do, @Psidom's first suggestion looks reasonable.  In particular, you probably don't need a masked array.  Just index a regular array with a boolean array.

Answer (score 0):

`masked_X = np.where(mask, X, 0)` is the fastest & the simplest way to mask a data :

```
X = np.array([[2,-1,4],
              [3,-3,1],
              [9,-7,2]])

mask = np.identity(3)
```

time measure :

```
%timeit np.where(mask,X,0)
```

> 969 ns ± 14.6 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)

```
%timeit np.ma.array(X, mask=mask)
```

> 6.47 µs ± 85.9 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)

I let you conclude !