# torch equivalent of numpy.r_

Tags: python, numpy, pytorch

numpy has [`.r_`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.r_.html)

which

> Translates slice objects to concatenation along the first axis.
>
> This is a simple way to build up arrays quickly. There are two use
> cases.
>
> If the index expression contains comma separated arrays, then stack them along their first axis.
>
> If the index expression contains slice notation or scalars then create a 1-D array with a range indicated by the slice notation.

I am looking for a torch equivalent, originally to answer to a comment [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67649104/is-there-a-verctorized-approach-in-pytorch-to-get-this-result/67649397?noredirect=1#comment119574022_67649397), but also in general.

Comment: Fundamentally it is just `np.concatenate` with a cute way of specifying `arange` or `linspace`.  You shouldn't need to find an exact equivalent.

Comment: Also `r_` is most often used to generate a discontinuous array/list of indices.  `torch` objects can be indexed with numpy arrays, can't they?  In which case there's no need to find/create an equivalent.

Comment: @hpaulj "most often not" strictly means "sometimes you do", in fact I use it very often