# numpy Mask 2d array rows by ranges from 1d array

Tags: python, numpy

I have this 1d array which represents the ranges of valid values.

```
ranges = np.array([1, 2, 0])
```

and i have multiple 2d arrays that have values, which i want to mask by index based on the ranges above.

```
matrixes = np.array([[0, 1, 2],
                     [3, 4, 5],
                     [6, 7, 8]])
```

So each value in "ranges" represents the number of rows that have valid values in "matrixes" (the columns correspond to each-other), so the masking would return something like:

```
              ([[True,  True,  False],
                [False, True,  False],
                [False, False, False]])
```

The first column has 1 valid value, the first.
The second column has 2 valid values... etc.

I tried several other topics but could not figure out how to do it...
ex: [How to properly mask a numpy 2D array?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38193958/how-to-properly-mask-a-numpy-2d-array)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use broadcasting:

```
out = np.arange(matrixes.shape[0])[:,None]<ranges
```

Output:

```
[[ True  True False]
 [False  True False]
 [False False False]]
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for the reply. With some transposing it seems to work fine, although a bit one-line-ish :) Thank you.